# Is it acceptable to use a stop size larger than length of list when using colon to slice list in Python?

Tags: python, list, slice

I want to find the first 3 elements in list by using `my_list[:3]`, but I cannot guarantee that the list will be at least length 3.

I can only find examples with given list and small stop. So, I want to know whether `my_list[:3]` is acceptable without checking the length of list.

I have tried by myself and it works well. But I want to see whether any description of doc.

Comment: Yes, that works fine.

Comment: It takes far less time to test it in the shell than it does to write a question on Stack Overflow. Python is interactive -- so interact with it.

Comment: if list is shorter then 3 elements then `[:3]` gives less elements without error - so you will have to check length if you need 3rd element from `my_list[:3]` .

Comment: BTW: this is the `stop` not the `step` of a slice: `[start:stop:step]`

Comment: @AChampion thanks for your correction.

Comment: @JohnColeman I tried. It works well, but is there any clear instructions?

Comment: @user3801587 The tutorial  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html says "out of range slice indexes are handled gracefully when used for slicing"

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks. That's what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> li=[1,2,3]
```

There are really only two cases to consider.

1) If a slice that extends beyond the end of the list, it will deliver the overlap of defined elements and an empty list beyond without error:

```
>>> li[2:]
[3]
>>> li[3:]
[]
>>> li[5555:]
[]
>>> li[1:55555]
[2, 3]
>>> li[555:55555]
[]
```

2) Given a slice assignment, the overlapping elements are replaced and the remaining elements are appended without error:

```
>>> li[1:5]=[12,13,14,15,16]
>>> li
[1, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 15]
>>> li[555:556]=[555,556]
>>> li
[1, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 15, 555, 556]
```

The last case there, the slice assignment was to non existing elements are were therefore just appended to the existing elements.

However, if the right hand slice does not match existing elements on the left hand, there can be a `ValueError` for non existing elements with an extended slice (i.e., if you have `list_object[start:stop:step]`):

```
>>> li
[1, 2, 3]
>>> li[1:7:2]=range(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 4 to extended slice of size 1
```

But if they are existing, you can do an extended slice assignment:

```
>>> li=['X']*10
>>> li
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
>>> li[1:10:2]=range(5)
>>> li
['X', 0, 'X', 1, 'X', 2, 'X', 3, 'X', 4]
```

Most of the time -- it works as expected. If you want to use a step for assignments the elements need to be existing.

Answer (score 3):

This is fine regardless of the length of the list.

This is the behavior of the call you're trying to make:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2]
a[:3]
>>>[1,2,3]
b[:3]
>>>[1,2]
```

Essentially it will behave exactly as you want to.